# netsuite add button to a record

Tags: button, netsuite

I'm really new to NetSuite programming, and I'm having troubles adding a button to a record.

I want to add the button "Create Lead" next to the "Edit" and "Back" buttons of a record.

I have created a user event script, and this is my before load function:

```
function beforeLoad_addButton(type, form, request){
form.setScript(customscript_cue_new_lead_record);
form.addButton('custpage_add_createlead_button', 'Create Lead', 'createLeadRecord()');
}
```

I am setting a script to call a function on an other .js file.

This doesn't add a button like I would want it to. Can anyone help me figure this out? Thanks.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The first thing I see is that your call to .setScript needs to pass the ID as a string; you have no quotes. It should be:

```
form.setScript('customscript_cue_new_lead_record');
```

Not sure if this was just a typo, but if that's how your code is, then this is probably throwing an error with something like "customscript_cue_new_lead_record is not defined" if you check the execution logs of your User Event script, which is stopping the rest of the script from running so your button isn't being added.

Everything else looks correct to me. You've got the custpage_ prefix on your button ID, and the code to execute as a String.

Comment: Another option is to customize the record's entry form instead of adding a button through script. Open any instance of the record of interest in _Edit Mode_, then click _Customize_ > _Customize Form_ just under the main navigation. Once there, you can use the _Custom Code_ tab to specify which source file to use, then use the _Actions_ > _Custom Actions_ tab to add a Button and the function called on click.

Comment: You are right I had figured it out yesterday but that was the problem, I was missing quotes.

Answer (score 4):

I don't see anything wrong with your script so make sure that you already deployed the said script as user-event script.

1. Setup > Customization > Scripts > New
2. Select Type: "User-Event"
3. In the new window fill up the necessary details and upload the js file. Make sure to put this function.

Before Load Function : beforeLoad_addButton

This will add the button in view and edit mode. Hope that helps.